# Double entries sent to mySQL from php script

Tags: php, mysql, duplicates, double

Even though I execute the the script once(one mysql_query), I get duplicate entries for some reason in the mySQL table.

These entries are not the same - the 'duplicate' entry will always have the same fields for the columns Timestamp and Picture, but the rest of the columns empty.

This is my script:

```
<?php

 session_start();

 $con = mysql_connect("Fruity.mysql.anyhost.com", "apples", "password");

 mysql_select_db("IAN_1");


 $username = $_SESSION['username'];
 $image = $_POST['image'];
 $post = $_POST['postdescription'];
 $idcolor = $_POST['idcolor'];
 $idbgcolor = $_POST['idbgcolor'];
 $timestamp = date("jS \of F Y h:i:s A P");



 $user_uploadposts = 
 "INSERT INTO $username (Timestamp, Image, Description, ID_color, ID_backgroundcolor)  
  VALUES ('$timestamp','$image', '$post','$idcolor','$idbgcolor')";


  mysql_query($user_uploadposts);


  mysql_close($con)

 ?>
```

**a screenshot of the problem** https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7efO.jpg

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.

Firstly, `$_POST['image']` suggests that we are dealing with files and if so, your form requires a valid enctype, a POST method, plus you would need to use `$_FILES` rather than `$_POST` if that is the case.

We also don't know if the session array has been set (no idea why you're using it here), and if your form elements contain matching name attributes.

I.e.: `<input type="text" name="postdescription">`

and your form should contain `method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"`.

If your form and PHP/MySQL are inside the same file, you will need to use `isset()` or `!empty()` for your variables. You may be getting undefined index notices, but they're not being displayed.

- Error reporting will tell you that.

I.e.: `if(!empty($_POST['postdescription'])){...}` same for the others.

What you also need to do is to have a primary key; that usually fixes things.

You also have a missing semi-colon for `mysql_close($con)` add it `mysql_close($con);`.

Replace your current code with:

```
mysql_query($user_uploadposts) or die(mysql_error());
```

in order to find errors and error reporting.

Plus, you are also using the [MySQL reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html) `Timestamp`, and it should be wrapped in ticks.

```
INSERT INTO $username (`Timestamp`, Image, ...
```

If that still doesn't work, then your incoming data may contain characters that MySQL will complain about.

- Escape your data.
- I.e.: `$post = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['postdescription']);`

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Displaying errors should only be done in staging, and never production.

---

Your present code is open to [**SQL injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/).

Use [**`mysqli` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements).

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. I think I may have phrased the question wrongly - there's no problem with sending data to the database. What I'm encountering now is some kind of glitch where the data gets send not once, but twice. Meaning instead of having just one row submitted to the database, I have two. I'm wondering why this duplicate exists.

Comment: @blurgoon You're welcome. Are you by any chance using some type of function? If not, then consider adding a primary key if one doesn't already exist. The problem may be happening on initial page load.

Comment: this is a screenshot of what I'm talking about with "duplicate entries". http://i.imgur.com/DaPiRYm.jpg 

I'm not sure what a primary key is, reading about it now.

Comment: @blurgoon I have a feeling that you're not showing me full code. You have one row that contains `jpg` for the extension, while the other one is inserted without it. You need to update your question with your full code including your HTML form.